# Monitoring pub/sub services

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, redis, monitoring, prometheus

For every service which read/write from/to topic in Kafka/Redis, there are some basic metrics which we want to have in Prometheus:

1. How "fast" the writes are for every topic
2. How "fast" the reads are for every topic

   - In Kafka, I may want to determine how "fast" each group-id reads.

To determine the "speed" of reading from a topic, one can think of a mechanism where someone publish the same message in intervals of `10` seconds and the consumer sends to Prometheus when it fully processed that message. If the graph show that the message was read every 12 seconds, it means that we have a lag of 2 seconds when reading ***any*** messages.

**It looks like a lot of repeated manual work** on every topic there is on the system.

#### Question

Is my proposal makes any sense? Are there any best-practice/tools on how to determine "lags"/"speed" of reading/writing from every topic in redis/kafka/... in Prometheus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue once.

Maintaining the each topic metrics manually is very tiring and not at all scalable.

I switched over to using kafka_consumergroup_lag metric from the [kafka_exporter](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter)
This along with the consumergroup,topic labels were enough to let us know to know which topic was not being read/lagging behind and by which consumer group.

Also has other metrics like the rate of meassages being read.

As for converting this lag in terms of time, either attach an produce time to kafka message and read it at the other end of the kafka pipeline and export the difference in time via micrometer from the application to Prometheus.

Or better still:- use tracing to track each message in the piepline using OpenTracing tools like [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/)

Use [this](https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter) for Redis monitoring.

All these exporters send the data in the Prometheus format and can be directly integrated.

Comment: That sounds great. Thanks!

Comment: Also, to calculate the lag of each consumer-group-id, you mentioned 2 ways: `kafka_consumergroup_lag` metric (kafka_exporter) and manually calculating it: "attach an produce time to kafka message...". What do you recommend and why?

Comment: I,for one, have never had to measure lag in terms of time,the lags in term of number of messages is good enough for most cases.My priority would be use exporter then tracing and then time headers which requires adding extra efforts around intrumenting the application.

Comment: Hi @Stav me know if I can help you further